# Kendo DataSource read() fails because of redirection for authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, azure, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC website that uses kendo controls in many of the views.

The code -

View

```
@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelectFor(model => model.certificateIds)
                .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 140%" })
                .DataTextField("CertificateName")
                .DataValueField("CertificateId")
                .Placeholder("Select Certificates")
                .DataSource(source =>
                    {
                        source.Read(read =>
                        {
                            read.Action("GetCertificates", "Account");
                        });
                    })
            )
```

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
    [OutputCache(Duration = int.MaxValue, Location = OutputCacheLocation.Any)]
    public JsonResult GetCertificates()
    {
        return Json(_accountsManager.GetAllCertificates(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

The problem - 
The read.Action() should get all the certificates for me, and 9 out of 10 times it does. But every now and then, when the session needs to replenished the application redirects the call to https://login.windows.net/ (I am using Azure AD for authentication). The redirection causes the whole read action to fail and no data is loaded in my dropdown.

The exact error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://login.windows.net/72...47/oauth2/autho…Rm...jc1. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://xyz-test.cloudapp.net' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I know this type of error usually happens when its a CORS issue, but I dont think this one is that. Similar redirections for authentication happen in other parts of the website and they work just fine.

Comment: Same issue as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27412651/waad-doesnt-refresh-access-token-from-javascript) The suggested answer is to use ADAL.JS